# ogr2ogr error loading KML file in PostGIS with PHP

Tags: postgis, kml, ogr2ogr, php

So I have a KML file that I want to save to my PostGIS database,
Currently I have the following code using PHP:

```
$file = $request->file("item");

$name   = time();
$name   = $name . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$temp = 'uploads/' . $user_app->id . '/kml/';
$path = public_path('uploads/' . $user_app->id . '/kml/');
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
$path   = public_path() . '/uploads/' . $user_app->id . '/kml/';
$command = "ogr2ogr  -f PostgreSQL PG:\"host=".$HOST." dbname=".$DBNAME." port=".$PORT." user=".$USER." password=".$PASSWORD."\"   ".$path.$name."  -nln siap 2>&1";

Log::debug($command);
$res = shell_exec($command) ;
Log::debug($res);
```

This is the command line,

```
ogr2ogr  -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgis_24_sample port=5432 user=postgres password=123456"   C:\xampp\htdocs\siap-padron\public/uploads/2044492/kml/1597284059.kml  -nln siap 2>&1
```

If I run it in PowerShell or in the system symbol it inserts it correctly in the PostGIS base, but when it is run in PHP it gives me the following error:

```
local.DEBUG: FAILURE: Unable to open datasource `C:/xampp/htdocs/siap-padron/public/uploads/2044492/kml/1597284059.kml' with the following drivers.
-> `JP2ECW'......
```

Any comment would be very helpful.

Comment: It looks like GDAL tries to open the kml file with raster drivers. I do not know why. EDIT: wrong thinking, JPEG 2000 can contain also vector data and therefore the JP2ECW driver was tested as well.

Answer (score 1):

The error came out because my kml file path was wrong, the correct way is as follows

```
ogr2ogr  -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgis_24_sample port=5432 user=postgres password=123456"   C:/xampp/htdocs/siap-padron/public/uploads/2044492/kml/1597328869.kml  -nln siap 2>&1
```